# How are string collections serialized in a custom C# class for Contacts with the Outlook REST API?

Tags: c#, outlook, json.net, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I've generated a C# class from sample JSON output using the Graph Explorer with Contacts (as per below).  However, when I pass the serialized object (using JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myclass)) with null values for string array properties to a POST operation to create the Contact I get the following error in the response:

> A null value was found for the property named 'BusinessPhones', which
>   has the expected type 'Collection(Edm.String)[Nullable=False]'. The
>   expected type 'Collection(Edm.String)[Nullable=False]' does not allow
>   null values.

(for reference, these are the supported Contact properties: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#contact)

Here's an example of the raw JSON:

```
{"AssistantName":null,"Birthday":null,"BusinessAddress":null,"BusinessPhones":null,"Categories":null,"Children":null,"CompanyName":"Fun Toys and Bikes","Department":null,"DisplayName":"Mr. Robert E. Ahlering","EmailAddresses":[{"Address":"robert@funtoys.com","Name":"Robert E. Ahlering (robert@funtoys.com)"}],"FileAs":null,"Generation":null,"GivenName":"Robert","HomeAddress":null,"Initials":null,"JobTitle":"Owner","Manager":null,"MiddleName":null,"MobilePhone1":null,"NickName":null,"OfficeLocation":null,"OtherAddress":null,"PersonalNotes":null,"Profession":null,"SpouseName":null,"Surname":"Ahlering","Title":null,"YomiCompanyName":null,"YomiGivenName":null,"YomiSurname":null}
```

I believe the correct formatting for a null BusinessPhones value (to pick one of the string arrays) should be "BusinessPhones":[], and not "BusinessPhones:null".

So how do I implement string array/collection properties in the class to accommodate this?

```
public partial class OutlookContact
{
    public partial class Businessaddress
    {
        public object City { get; set; }

        public object CountryOrRegion { get; set; }

        public object PostalCode { get; set; }

        public object State { get; set; }

        public object Street { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Emailaddress
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Homeaddress
    {
        public string City { get; set; }

        public object CountryOrRegion { get; set; }

        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        public string State { get; set; }

        public string Street { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Otheraddress
    {
        public object City { get; set; }

        public object CountryOrRegion { get; set; }

        public object PostalCode { get; set; }

        public object State { get; set; }

        public object Street { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Rootobject
    {
        public object AssistantName { get; set; }

        public DateTime? Birthday { get; set; }

        public Businessaddress BusinessAddress { get; set; }

        public string[] BusinessPhones { get; set; }

        public object[] Categories { get; set; }

        public object[] Children { get; set; }

        public object CompanyName { get; set; }

        public string Department { get; set; }

        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        public Emailaddress[] EmailAddresses { get; set; }

        public string FileAs { get; set; }

        public object Generation { get; set; }

        public string GivenName { get; set; }

        public Homeaddress HomeAddress { get; set; }

        public object Initials { get; set; }

        public string JobTitle { get; set; }

        public object Manager { get; set; }

        public object MiddleName { get; set; }

        public object MobilePhone1 { get; set; }

        public object NickName { get; set; }

        public string OfficeLocation { get; set; }

        public Otheraddress OtherAddress { get; set; }

        public object PersonalNotes { get; set; }

        public object Profession { get; set; }

        public object SpouseName { get; set; }

        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public object Title { get; set; }

        public object YomiCompanyName { get; set; }

        public object YomiGivenName { get; set; }

        public object YomiSurname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize `BusinessPhones` property to an empty array in the constructor of `RootObject` class as following.

```
public partial class RootObject
{
    public RootObject()
    {
        this.BusinessPhones = new string[0];
    }

    // rest of the class...
}
```

And if that's not possible, you need to make sure that the `BusinessPgones` is initialized to empty array before you serialize it to JSON string.

```
var rootObject = new RootObject();
rootObject.BusinessPhones = new string[];
// set other properties of rootObject
//Serialize rootObject to JSON
// Call rest API.
```

This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the error `null` collection is not allowed. You should be able to use any empty collection instead:

```
"BusinessPhones": []
```